# Postfix using virtual.db file instead of mysql table

Tags: email, debian, postfix, alias

I have specified `virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf`, but still I got errors like

> warning: hash:/etc/postfix/virtual is unavailable. open database /etc/postfix/virtual.db: No such file or directory

If I create the virtual and virtual.db files, everything works fine, but I want my virtual user account to be stored in DB, not if a file.

Why does postfix use the virtual.db file instead of db table?

`postconf -n`:

```
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
mydestination = localhost
non_smtpd_milters = unix:/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_milters = unix:/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = example.tst
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/dovecot/dovecot.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_transport = dovecot
```

Actually I have /etc/postfix/virtual in master.cf:

```
submission inet n - - - - smtpd
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
  -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
  -o smtpd_sasl_local_domain=$myhostname
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_sender_login_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=reject_sender_login_mismatch
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=reject_non_fqdn_recipient,reject_unknown_recipient_domain,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
```

Comment: You did `postfix reload`, right?

Comment: Do you get virtual.db anywhere when you run 'postconf'?

Comment: @dan, yes, of cource

Comment: @tim-stoop no, I don't

Comment: You sure `postconf | grep /etc/postfix/virtual` doesn't show the hashmap being referenced?

Comment: @dan, yes, I've checked it with grep several times trying to find anything unusual. postconf | grep /etc/postfix/virtual returns nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the line `-o smtpd_sender_login_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/virtual` in master.cf. I forgot to look there, because this exact configuration was running fine for months on another my server.

Comment: Would you like to accept this answer so this question wasn't left in unanswered state?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved that by modifying the line in `etc/postfix/main.cf`  :

```
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

to

```
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
```

(or as an alternative, just create the `etc/postfix/virtual` file with content):

```
your_linux_username:  your_email@gmail.com
```

then restart postfix:  `sudo systemctl restart postfix` and then mails were sent.